# Drupal script cannot change folder and file permissions in my VPS

Tags: users

Drupal always change permissions of /sites/default and settings.php. Now I move it in my VPS and maybe I misconfigure user www-data access but i cannot remember what exactly.

Now Drupal does not change permissions.

This problem caused by my mistakes.

Please, how to return proper configuration to have a Drupal works fine?

Comment: are your vps running on ubuntu?

Comment: no. debian 8.2 nginx +php5-fpm

Comment: I think you just need to give  file owner of www-data to the drupal folder. In ubuntu it's `sudo chown www-data -R drupal`. Dunno about debian.

Comment: Distro doesn't matter. Everything you need to know about Drupal and permissions is here: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924 complete with a helpful bash script.

Comment: thank you all. i made it. i cannot read with this question such a big article: i only found that all files and folders need to have www-data group. but this is did not solve my task: i want to configure server that drupal able to change permissions by itself.